# How do I use a double grep comparison inside a bash if/else?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How do I use a double grep comparison inside a bash if/else ?

I'm tring to run:

```
if [grep  -q $HOSTNAME /etc/hosts] && [grep  -q $IP /etc/hosts]

then

    echo $HOSTNAME and $IP is found into /etc/hosts, test passed OK.

else

    # code if not found
    echo The Hostname $HOSTNAME'/'IP $IP is not found in /etc/hosts, please append it manually. 
    exit 1;
fi
```

but getting error message: `*too many arguments*`

What is wrong?

Comment: The  `test` command (aka `[`) is for checking files and compare values. Remove the `[`  `]` from your `grep`.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you should execute:

```
if grep -q "foo" /etc/hosts && grep -q "bar" /etc/hosts; then
   # Both foo and bar exist within /etc/hosts.
else
   # Either foo or bar or both, doesn't exist in /etc/hosts.
fi
```

The reason for your error is that you fail to use the `[` command.
Just like any other command, `[` accepts arguments which you fail to provide correctly by not separating it from its arguments.

`[` or `test` is the *POSIX* test command. It can do simple tests on files and strings. In Bash, I recommend you to use the more powerful `[[` keyword. `[[` can do pattern matching, is faster and safer to use ( read further at [Bash FAQ 31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)).

Though, as you can see in my solution above, your case does not require `[` nor `[[`, but just an `if` statement to ask for the *exit status** of `grep`.

---

*exit status**: Every Unix process returns an exit status code to its parent. This is an unsigned 8-bit value, a number from 0 to 255 inclusive. Your script returns the exit status from the last command it 
                executed, unless you specifically call `exit` with a value. Functions also return values, using `return`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if grep  -q $HOSTNAME /etc/hosts && grep  -q $IP /etc/hosts
then
    echo "$HOSTNAME and $IP is found into /etc/hosts, test passed OK."
else
    # code if not found
    echo "The Hostname $HOSTNAME'/'IP $IP is not found in /etc/hosts, please append it manually." 
    exit 1;
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax fails: `if [grep -q $HOSTNAME /etc/hosts]` should be `if [ $(grep  -q $HOSTNAME /etc/hosts) ]`: With spaces around the brachets and the grep as a subcommand.
This still not works because `if` is expecting something to test and not the result of a test. I normally use `if [ $(grep -c string file) -gt 0 ]` but you can also use `if [ -n "$(grep string file)" ]`.

I think  you want the host and ip on the same line. In that case use:

```
if [ -n "$(grep -E "${IP}.*${HOSTNAME}" /etc/hosts)" ]; then
   echo "Found"
fi

# or (using the grep -q)
grep -Eq "${IP}.*${HOSTNAME}" /etc/hosts
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

# or (shorter, harder to read for colleages, using the grep -q)
grep -Eq "${IP}.*${HOSTNAME}" /etc/hosts)" && echo "Found"
```

When you really want two tests, consider 2 independant if-statements.